# Sorted Iteration of HashMap Java

Tags: java

I know that HashMap is not sorted but is there any away i can create iterator which returns values in sorted order of key. I can use Sorted versions of the collections but I am looking for a way to do the same with Hash Based map.

Answer (score 3):

Any such iterator would have to internally sort all the keys of the `HashMap` in order to be able to iterate over them in sorted order. It would be more efficient to use an already sorted `Map` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TreeMap since its a sorted map.

Comment: Yes I can, I was looking for a way to do the same using HashMap

Answer (score 0):

With Java 8 this is very simple:

```
import static java.util.Map.Entry.comparingByKey;

public <K extends Comparable<? super K>, V> Iterator<V> orderedIterator(final Map<K, V> map) {
    return map.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(comparingByKey())
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .iterator();
}
```

Note, this is **slow**, as the `Stream` needs to be sorted each time - so iteration becomes `O(n lg n)` rather than `O(n)`. If you need to do this a lot, you would be better off using a `TreeMap` -  where insertion is `O(lg n)` (rather than `O(1)`) but iteration is still `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is completely possible, at least from a map point of view, although we could create a special hash map the returns keys from a sort order.

The map could extend `HashMap` and have a variable the contains the sort order and then have a method that returns the keys and values in the sort order.

You could have a static utility method that takes a `HashMap` and returns an array of `Map.Entry`s in the sort order.

While the above may work, `TreeMap` is probably the way to go. It's designed for this task and was written by Josh Blotch so it's bound to be fast at what it does. Reinventing the wheel always takes longer and doesn't work as well.

**Note: This depends on the use case. If you only need to use the sorted values once, then the utility method or custom `HashMap` implementation will be best. If you're planning on using the `Map` often, then go with a `TreeMap`.**

Comment: Depends. If you only need to do it once; then the cost of sorting the `entrySet` would be less than the cost of maintaining a `TreeMap`. `TreeMap` is very slow compared to a `HashMap` - it also required more space. Your last paragraph really depends on the use case - and it requires benchmarking to work out which approach would be better.

Comment: @Boris the Spider I assumed that the op wants to use the sorted `HashMap` implementation rather often or a simple utility method would be best here. Although I will update the answer to reflect that.